# Duda con formato de salida pgAdmin III

Tags: sql, postgresql

mi duda es la siguiente:

existe alguna forma de que al generar una consulta en postgreSql la primera fila salga con el sigo ================, tal como lo muestra el siguiente ejemplo:

```
  campo1   campo2   campo3   campo4
1 =================================
2  dato1    dato2    dato3    dato4
3  dato5    dato6    dato7    dato8
```

Estoy usando pgAdmin III, no psql console.

con el siguiente codigo:

```
do
$$
declare
r record;
begin
RAISE NOTICE 'nombre1                    nombre2';
RAISE NOTICE '================================';

for r in SELECT upper(nombre1), nombre2
from tabla
order by nombre1 desc loop
raise notice'%', r ;
end loop;
end;
$$
```

eh logrado esto:

```
NOTICE:  nombre1                  nombre2
NOTICE:  ================================
NOTICE:  ("dato1", dato2)
NOTICE:  ("dato3", dato4)
NOTICE:  ("dato5", dato6)
NOTICE:  ("dato7", dato8)
```

alguna forma de modificar la salida, que no salga ente comillas "", mas separado, mas bonito?.

saludos!

Comment: No se entiende qué sentido tiene lo que pides. pgAdmin no produce una salida textual sino en una grilla, que puede exportarse a texto como CSV, o como reporte html.

Comment: ¿Existe alguna manera de obtener esa salida en texto (sin el "=====")? ¿cómo se hace? Sabiendo eso quizás podamos ayudarte

Comment: Entonces no puedo lograr ese formato de salida mediante pgAdmin?

Comment: lo eh modificado, espero me puedan ayudar